# Confused about intuition behind Lie derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-derivative

I'm trying to fix my intuition behind $\mathcal L_X T$, where $T$ is any tensor field. I'd prefer explanations that are not along the lines of $\mathcal L_XY=[X,Y]$ (I'm not sure how this extends to the case where $Y$ is an arbitrary tensor field).

I have two specific questions, but explanations beyond answering these questions are more than welcome.

1. Denote the flow of $X$ by $\varphi$. Certainly $(\mathcal L_XT)_p$ depends on both $X|_U$ and $T|_U$, where $U$ is an arbitrarily small neighborhood of $p$. But does it depend on the values of $X$ and $T$ on all of $U$, or just their values on the flow line, i.e., $\{\varphi_t(p)\}_{t\in\mathbf R}\cap U$? More specifically, is there an explicit example of $X$, $X'$ (with flow $\varphi'$), and $T$, such that for some $p$, we have $\varphi_t(p)=\varphi'_t(p)$ (i.e., $X=X'$ on the flow line through $p$) but $(\mathcal L_XT)_p\neq(\mathcal L_{X'}T)_p$?
2. [Lee's *Riemannian Manifolds*, Exercise 4-3(b).] Show that there is a vector field on $\mathbf R^2$ that vanishes along the $x$-axis, but whose Lie derivative with respect to $\partial_x$ does not vanish on the $x$-axis.

   My failed attempt at this problem: Suppose $V=f\partial_x + g\partial_y$ is such a vector field. Then $f(x,0)=g(x,0)=0$ for all $x$ by hypothesis. Using $\mathcal L_XY=(XY^i-YX^i)\partial_i$, we have $\mathcal L_{\partial_x}V=(\partial_xf-0)\partial_x+(\partial_xg-0)\partial_y$, which is supposed to be nonzero somewhere on the $x$-axis, i.e., there is some $x_0$ such that $\partial_xf(x_0,0)\neq0$ or $\partial_xg(x_0,0)\neq0$. Without loss of generality, assume $\partial_xf(x_0,0)\neq0$. So now we have to come up with some $f:\mathbf R^2\to\mathbf R$ such that $f(x,0)=0$ for all $x$ but $\partial_xf(x_0,0)\neq0$ for some $x$, which is a contradiction. What went wrong?

Comment: Assigning to a manifold the tensor fields on it of a particular type is a functor with respect to diffeomorphisms, so there is a well-defined notion of what it means for a diffeomorphism to act on tensor fields. The Lie derivative is the induced action of infinitesimal diffeomorphisms (which are vector fields).

Comment: I'm not terribly comfortable with (even the most basic) category theory, but here's an attempt at understanding what you're saying: $T^m_n$ is a functor (I'm not entirely sure how it acts on morphisms), so in particular it takes $\operatorname{Diff}(M)$ to some subgroup of $\operatorname{Hom}(T^m_n(M),T^m_n(M))$. I'm completely lost with regards to the comment about the induced action of infinitesimal diffeomorphisms. Vector fields are infinitesimal diffeomorphisms - this seems intuitive enough, but how exactly does this induce "infinitesimal things" in the other category? Thanks!

Comment: Take a one-parameter family of diffeomorphisms (for example, the flow of some vector field) and look at how it acts on tensor fields, then differentiate it.

Comment: If you have two specific questions, you should consider asking two separate questions. Makes the answers easier to search, allows the effort of answering your questions to be split over multiple authors, etc..

Comment: The problem you quoted from my _Riemannian Manifolds_ book is incorrectly stated. There's a correction to it in my [errata list](http://www.math.washington.edu/~lee/Books/Riemannian/errata.pdf)..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the intuition behind the Lie derivative I can maybe add a bit to the comment by Qiaochu Yuan: The simplest way to understand the differentiation is to consider the flows $\phi_t$, use them to pull back $T$ and then evaluate in the point $p$. This lies in the fiber of the appropriate tensor bundle at $p$ for any value of $t$. Hence you obtain a smooth curve in a finite dimensional vector space, and you can simply differentiate this in $t=0$ to obtain an element of that vector space. Work would be needed to deduce that this depends smoothly on $p$, but for the purpose of intuition that's not neccesary.

This description also implies the answer to question 1, but I can give you a more direct argument: It is true that the Lie derivative is a local operator, so the value of $\mathcal L_XT$ in a point $p$ depends only on the restrictions of $X$ and $T$ to an arbitrarily small neighborhood $U$ of $X$. But much more is true, because the Lie derivative is a first order differential operator. This means that it depends only on the one-jets of $X$ and $T$ in $p$. (There are various ways to make this explicit.) If you look at the coordinate formula for the Lie derivative, you see that to compute $\mathcal L_XT(p)$ you only need the components of $T$ and their derivatives in direction $X(p)$. Hence it is indeed true that the value of $\mathcal L_XT$ in $p$ depends only on the restriction of $T$ to the flow line of $X$ through $p$.

Question 2 is anserwered in Jack Lee's comment.

Comment: I think I may have found a counterexample to question 1. Work in $\mathbf R^2$. For vector fields $X=\partial_x$ and $Y=\partial_y$, we have $\mathcal L_XY=[X,Y]=0$. Now consider $Z=\partial_x+y\partial_y$. Note that $Z$ agrees with $X$ on the $x$-axis. But $\mathcal L_ZY=[Z,Y]=-\partial_y$.

Comment: I think I see the problem. There was a misunderstanding on the ambiguous phrasing of my question. I asked if $\mathcal L_XT$ depends on just the values of $X$ and $T$ on the flow line. You interpreted that as "if I change the values of $T$ outside the flow line, does it change $\mathcal L_XT$?" The answer is clearly no. But what I intended to ask was clarified by "More specifically, ..." So the complete answer is that it depends on the values of $X$ on *all of $U$* but only on the values of $T$ on the flow line.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. My main point was to look at "the operator $\mathcal L_X$", so my emphasis was on the question "what information about $T$ do you need in order to determine $\mathcal L_XT(p)$". The answer to this is that you need the value of $T$ in $p$ in its derivative in direction $X(p)$. In particular, if $T$ and $\tilde T$ coincide along the flow line of $X$ through $p$, then $\mathcal L_XT(p)=\mathcal L_X\tilde T(p)$ (and hence the Lie derivatives coincide along the flow line). If you are primarlly interested in $X$, just use that $\mathcal L_XT=-\mathcal L_TX$.